# Angular app stops routing after clicking on one route

Tags: angular, routes

I am new to Angular and was working with the Router module.
Below I have a Servers component which has 3 servers and when I click on each server it opens the server's individual component(server component) is displayed in the same page.
When I click on any server the server component for that server is displayed beside but it works for only 1 of the 3 servers. After a server is clicked the server's individual page is displayed beside but when we click on remaining servers the same action does not repeat for them.
Please let me know why this is happening. Below is the app.module.TS ,servers.component.TS , server.component.TS and the server.component.HTMl in respective order.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component';
import { UserComponent } from './users/user/user.component';
import { EditServerComponent } from './servers/edit-server/edit-server.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './servers/server/server.component';
import { ServersService } from './servers/servers.service';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes =[
  {path:"users",component:UsersComponent,
children:[
  {path:":id/:name", component:UserComponent},
]},

  {path:"",component:HomeComponent},

  {path:"servers", component:ServersComponent, children:[
    {path:":id" , component:ServerComponent},
    {path:":id/edit", component:EditServerComponent},
  ]
}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    ServersComponent,
    UserComponent,
    EditServerComponent,
    ServerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),

  ],
  providers: [ServersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Servers.component.HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a
        class="list-group-item"
        *ngFor="let server of servers"
        [routerLink] = "['/servers', server.id]"
        [queryParams]="{editable:1}"
        fragment="loading">
        {{ server.name }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Server.component.TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServersService } from '../servers.service';
import { Router , ActivatedRoute} from  '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server',
  templateUrl: './server.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server.component.css']
})
export class ServerComponent implements OnInit {
  server: {id: number, name: string, status: string};
  id:number;
  queryParamsfromURL:{queryparams:""} = {queryparams:""};
  fragmentsFromURL:string=""

  constructor(private serversService: ServersService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

       }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {this.id = +params['id']}
    )
    this.server = this.serversService.getServer(+this.id);
    console.log(this.server);
//queryparams and fragments 
    this.queryParamsfromURL.queryparams = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['editable'];
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      newqueryparams => {this.queryParamsfromURL = newqueryparams.editable}
    );
    
    this.fragmentsFromURL = this.route.snapshot.fragment;
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(
      fragmentchange => {this.fragmentsFromURL = fragmentchange}
    )   
  }
}
```

**Server.component.HTML**

```
<div >
<h5> {{server.name}}</h5>
<p>Server status is {{server.status}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up the route listener inside `ngOnInit` which executes one time only. This is the root cause.

Here is the code

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {this.id = +params['id']}
    )
    this.server = this.serversService.getServer(+this.id);
```

What you wanted is the `serverService` get called whenever the route change, however, that piece of code is outside of the `subscribe`. So the `this.id` get updated but that line `this.server` never get run again.

We want route changes => call the service => service invocation's code should be placed inside the `subscribe` body

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
          params => {
                this.id = +params['id']
                this.server = this.serversService.getServer(+this.id);
          })
```

Comment: yes, this makes sense and it works. I forgot that only the subscribe method runs once the id is updated. I was assuming once the ID is updated the rest of code also will be executed. but it was under ngOnit() which runs only once. 
thanks for pointing this out. I was stuck on this for a day.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try adding the href="#" attribute in the anchor tag in servers.component.html.It may work.

Servers.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a
        href="#"        // try this
        class="list-group-item"
        *ngFor="let server of servers"
        [routerLink] = "['/servers', server.id]"
        [queryParams]="{editable:1}"
        fragment="loading">
        {{ server.name }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried adding  href="#" but didn't work. It still loads the server component for only 1 of the 3 servers.